# Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError

Tags: laravel-5

i'm trying to seed data to database using laravel.

this is my factory model

```
$factory->define(App\product::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
return [
    'name' => $faker->name,
    'description' => $faker->description,
    'price' =>$faker->price,
    'image' => $faker->image,
    'value' => $faker->value,
    'category_id' => $faker->category_id,
    'is_voucher' => $faker->is_voucher,
    'voucher_id' => $faker->voucher_id,

];
```

});

in the producttableseed

```
public function run()
{
 $product = factory(product::class, 10)->create();}
```

and when i run  php artisan db:seed
i get this error

Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError  : Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factory::{closure}() must be an instance of Faker\Generator\Generator, instance of Faker\Generator given

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the line

```
use Faker\Generator as Faker;
```

before you define your factory? This, plus changing first line to this

```
$factory->define(App\product::class, function (Faker $faker) {
```

works for me.

Also, be careful with

```
$product = factory(product::class, 10)->create();}
```

You are seeding 10 database entries here. Your variable name being singular, looks like you might be up for a surprise when you try working with an array that has multiple entries.